# simulate data from regression line in python

Tags: regression, python

If I have a regression line and an r squared is there a simple numpy (or some other python library) command to randomly draw, say, y values for an x that are consistent with the regression? The same way you could just draw a random value from a distribution?

Thanks!

edit: I have the equation for my regression line and an r^2 value. That r^2 value should provide some information about the distribution of data points around my line, no? If I just call this y=random.gauss()*x+b haven't I lost the information in my r^2? Or would this be incorporated into the stdv, if so how? Sorry, I just haven't worked with regression much before.

Comment: That's what a gaussian random number generator is for.  Are you unclear on gaussian random number generators?  Or unclear on the y=mx+b to apply the regression slope and offset to a random value? Or are you looking for a function that combines `y=random.gauss()*x+b` into some kind of generator expression? Can you be more specific about what's confusing you?

Answer (score 2):

Luckily there is no need for brute force :). To get a relationship between the `R^2` and the standard deviation of the residuals it is easiest to start at the definition of the `R^2`:

```
R^2 = SSR / SST    (1)
```

where `SSR` is the sums of squares of the regression, i.e. `(sum((y'-mean(y))^2)` where `y'` are the values on the regression line, and SST is the total sums of squares, i.e. `sum((y - mean(y))^2)` where `y` are the observations. So effectively the `R^2` is the fraction of between the total amount of variance and the amount of variance explained by the regression model (or line). For our purpose we need to re express `SSR` as `SST - SSE`, where `SSE` are the sums of squares between the regression line and the observations. `SSE` is variance which is not explained by the regression model. Rewriting (1):

```
R^2 = (SST - SSE) / SST = 1 - SSE / SST
```

expressing for `SSE`:

```
SSE = (1 - R^2) SST
```

If we note that to go for sums of squares to variance we need to divide by `N-1` this becomes:

```
VAR_E = (1 - R^2) VAR_T
```

to get the standard deviation of the residuals:

```
SD_E = sqrt((1 - R^2) VAR_T)
```

and taking the VAR out of the parentheses:

```
SD_E = sqrt(1 - R^2) SD_T
```

So you need the `R^2` and the total standard deviation of the dataset. To verify this, check any introductory statistics book.

Comment: +1 Since the total variance is sum( d**2 for d in deviations ) (from my answer) there seems the a little brute force in this.  But the correct analysis of R**2 is very, very helpful.

Comment: The sum implies for all residuals, but in pythonanian that is what you say. I'm just to much used to vectorization in R, which should also work on numpy vectors I think...

Comment: Great answer, but the OP only wrote he has a regression line and an r squared, so I presume SD_T is unknown.

Comment: Hmm, good point, maybe the OP should present some more background. If he only has the line and the r squared he has a hard time simulating the exact residuals...

Comment: If the set of `x`'s is known or chosen, one could compute `SSR` and substitute `SSR+SSE` for `SST` in the equations. Unless I made a mistake, the solution is `SD_E = sqrt(1/R^2 - 1) SD_R`

Answer (score 1):

> If I just call this y=random.gauss()*x+b haven't I lost the information in my r^2?

Clearly.

However.

Reading the documentation, we see that [random.gauss](http://docs.python.org/library/random.html#random.gauss) takes two arguments.  A mean and a standard deviation.

The mean must be zero.

The standard deviation, however, needs to be adjusted to match your r**2.

When r**2 == 0, the standard deviation is high.  It should produce any value in the original range of the sample data.

As r**2 approaches 1, the standard deviation gets smaller.

How to compute the standard deviation value that reproduces your r**2?

Brute Force.

```
m, b = regression_model( some_data )
deviations = list( y - m*x+b for x, y in some_data )
```

This list of deviations is the essential ingredient in the standard deviation formula.

```
sd = math.sqrt( sum( d**2 for d in deviations ) / (len(some_data)-1) )
```

Now you can use `random.gauss(0,sd)` to reproduce the deviations in your original data.

See @PaulHiemstra's answer for a proper theoretical approach.

Comment: if you use numpy array there is no need for the list comprehension. If deviations is a numpy array, `sum( deviations^2)` should give the sums of squares.